# eclipse make java autocomplete to for template instead of the forEach method

Tags: java, eclipse

When writing a class that does not implement Iterable, I can write "for" and press enter to get the for template. which is great.

When writing a class that does implement Iterable, writing "for" will autocomplete to the forEach method. So when I want a for loop, I have to type "for", press down, and then press enter (but only if I'm in a class that implements Iterable).

If I type "for" I want eclipse to suggest the for template (it is the closest to what I typed). Is there a way to make eclipse do this? Or a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but you can go into Eclipse settings and modify the templates to be what you want.

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates

These templates are the ones that show up when you are typing.

Comment: The template is fine. The problem however is that when I type "for" I sometimes get this "forEach" function as first suggestion in the autocompletion.

Comment: You could give the forEach function a different name (not beginning with "for") if it bothers you that much.